# Creating an array from values in multiple columns without NaN values

Tags: python, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
         col1              col2            col3
0  (10.213,-20.23)   (120.1,-300.23)   (111.0, -231.1)
1  (11.22,-22.33)    (123.1,-302.23)   (nan, nan)
2  (122.22,-22.44)   (nan,nan)         (nan, nan)
```

I am trying to add all the sets in different columns but NOT nan sets. So the output would be something like:

```
                          col1              
0  ((10.213,-20.23),(120.1,-300.23),(111.0, -231.1))
1  ((11.22,-22.33),(123.1,-302.23)) 
2  (122.22,-22.44)
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way using the dataframe's `numpy` array representation and then assigning a list of lists to a single series.

The tricky part is to filter out `NaN` tuples; for this we can use `filter`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[(10.213, -20.23), (120.1, -300.23), (111.0, -231.1)],
                   [(11.22, -22.33), (123.1, -302.23), (np.nan, np.nan)],
                   [(122.22, -22.44), (np.nan, np.nan), (np.nan, np.nan)]],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

res = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [list(filter(lambda x: any(pd.notnull(j) for j in x), i))
                             for i in df.values.tolist()]})

print(res)

                                                col1
0  [(10.213, -20.23), (120.1, -300.23), (111.0, -...
1                [(11.22, -22.33), (123.1, -302.23)]
2                                 [(122.22, -22.44)]
```

Answer (score 2):

More or less vectorized version:

```
df[df.applymap(sum).notnull()].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(tuple)
```

Output:

```
0    ((10.213, -20.23), (120.1, -300.23), (111.0, -...
1                  ((11.22, -22.33), (123.1, -302.23))
2                                  ((122.22, -22.44),)
dtype: object
```

The idea:

```
In [727]: q.df2.applymap(sum).notnull()
Out[727]: 
   col1   col2   col3
0  True   True   True
1  True   True  False
2  True  False  False

In [728]: q.df2[q.df2.applymap(sum).notnull()]
Out[728]: 
               col1              col2             col3
0  (10.213, -20.23)  (120.1, -300.23)  (111.0, -231.1)
1   (11.22, -22.33)  (123.1, -302.23)              NaN
2  (122.22, -22.44)               NaN              NaN

In [729]: q.df2[q.df2.applymap(sum).notnull()].stack()
Out[729]: 
0  col1    (10.213, -20.23)
   col2    (120.1, -300.23)
   col3     (111.0, -231.1)
1  col1     (11.22, -22.33)
   col2    (123.1, -302.23)
2  col1    (122.22, -22.44)
dtype: object


In [730]: q.df2[q.df2.applymap(sum).notnull()].stack().groupby(level=0).apply(tuple)
Out[730]: 
0    ((10.213, -20.23), (120.1, -300.23), (111.0, -...
1                  ((11.22, -22.33), (123.1, -302.23))
2                                  ((122.22, -22.44),)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1. Can you comment (briefly) on which parts are vectorised? My understanding is `applymap(sum)` and `apply(tuple)` are not vectorised (not working with contiguous memory arrays). But `stack` and `groupby` possibly are?

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `.groupby` is vectorized, and so is `.notnull`. Of course, with slow `applymap` and `apply(tuple)` this does not matter much.